# My image in my database is not posting on my site (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, image, forms

so am created a form that takes two file buttons (for images) one for the thumbnail and the other for the main image and it has successfully taken the files and placed it in the database, it has also gotten their correct directory...but i have a problem...when it time to echo the images they dont show up...some please help me

here is the form  and the code(all in the same file called addimage.php):

```
<?php
include'includes/connect.php';

if($_POST['submit'])
 {
$img="main/";
$img= $img . basename($_FILES['photo1']['name']);

$tmb="thumb/";
$tmb= $tmb . basename($_FILES['photo2']['name']);


$imagename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['imagename']);
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$links = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['links']);
$pic1 = "main/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo1']['name']));
$pic2 = "thumb/" .(mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['photo2']['name']));

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $img));{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $tmb));{
{

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `portweb` ( `imagename`, `content`, `links`, `photo1`, `photo2`)  VALUES('$imagename', '$content', '$links', '$pic1', '$pic2')");
    echo "files upload success";
}
}
}
/*else
{
    echo "upload failed";   
}*/

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>upload pictures portfolio web</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="portweb.php">Back</a>
 <br />
 <form action="addportweb.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Main Image:</label>
 <input type="file" name="photo1" /><br />
<label>Thumb:</label>
<input type="file" name="photo2" /><br />
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="imagename" class="text_input" maxlength="100" /><br />
<label>Description:</label>
<textarea name="content" style="width: 300px; height:80px; padding: 5px; resize:none;" ></textarea>
<br />

<label>Link:</label> <textarea name="links" style="width: 100px; height:50px; padding: 5px; resize:none;" ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the function to help with the output...and also my problem:

```
function getportweb() {
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM portweb") or die(mysql_error());
      while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        echo "<img src =".$post['photo1']."/>";
            echo "<br>";

        echo "<img src =" . $post['photo2'] . "/>";
            echo"<br>";

        echo "<p>" . $post['imagename'] . "</p>";
            echo "<br>";
        echo "<p>" . $post['content'] . "</p>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<p>" . $post['links'] . "</p>";
            echo "<br>";

        echo "<a href=\"deleteportweb.php?id=" . $post['id'] . "\">Delete</a>";
        echo "<a href=\"editportweb.php?id=" . $post['id'] . "\">Edit</a>";
         echo "<br>";
         } 

}
```

i want to believe this is my problem

```
echo "<img src =".$post['photo1']."/>";
                echo "<br>";

            echo "<img src =" . $post['photo2'] . "/>";
                echo"<br>";
```

but i got nothing...please someone help

Comment: Have you viewed the source of the rendered page?  What are the img urls supposed to be, and what are they being printed out as?

Comment: the url is blah/admin/image/ and i have viewed it once i fill the form, they are saved in their respective folders but it does just show up once i want to post it.

Comment: so maybe you need to do echo `"<img src=blah/admin/image/ ".$post['photo1']."/>";`

Comment: okay i have tried that, still giving me the same problem(broken image link)what the hell am i doing wrong

Comment: You just need to make the URLs match. So look at the full url of your image e.g. `/admin/image/main/image.jpg`. The bit in your database is just `main/image.jpg` so you need to remove this bit,  and you'll end up with something like `/admin/image/`. This is what you need to put in:  echo "<img src=`/admin/image/`".$post['photo1']."/>";

Comment: "blah" is the main folder in my "htdoc" folder then "admin" folder, then "main" folder is where the images for the main images are stored and "thumb" folder is where thumbnails are stored(also inside the "admin" folder) this has been killing me for days.

Comment: oh never mind i figured it out, but i would like to thank you for your help, i will forever appreciate :) how i did it : echo "<img src =\"" . $post['photo1']."\">";

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
echo'<img src="'.$post['photo1'].'" />';
```