# echo my images on my index page PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, frontend, backend

i built a CMS and my image shows succesfully in the admin page(back-end) once i upload an image with the form  but once on the main index page(front-end) it shows that "broke image link"

here is my function to post the uploaded image on my admin page:

```
    function gettestimony() {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimony") or die(mysql_error());
  while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

    echo "<img src =\"" . $post['photo']."\">";

    echo "<p>" . $post['imagename'] . "</p>";
        echo "<br>";
    echo "<p>" . $post['test'] . "</p>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<p>" . $post['author'] . "</p>";
        echo "<br>";

    echo "<a href=\"deletetestimony.php?id=" . $post['id'] . "\">Delete</a>";
    echo "<a href=\"edittestimony.php?id=" . $post['id'] . "\">Edit</a>";
     echo "<br>";
     } 
}
```

and the directory is htdoc/blah/admin/include/functions.php
and the image is saved in htdoc/blah/admin/image/

for my main index, this is the function to post it:

```
   function gettestimony() {
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimony") or die(mysql_error());
  while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 

    echo "<div class='column second'>";
    echo "<p>" . $post['test'] . "</p>";
    echo "<img src =\"" . $post['photo']."\">";
    echo "</div>";


     } 
}
```

this is the code i use in both functions:

```
echo "<img src =\"" . $post['photo']."\">";
```

so like i said it works fine in admin page but my main page it doesn't....someone please help

Comment: This is probably because the path for the image in being viewed in index.php is different from that one in the admin panel.

Comment: Presumably by the time it's viewed on the main page, the image will be saved in `htdoc/blah/admin/image/` -- you need to set the path for the image in main.php

Comment: echo '<img src="'.$post['photo'].'" />';  
Check and see the url that image has is with respect you current web page url.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much exactly the same problem as your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26567773/my-image-in-my-database-is-not-posting-on-my-site-php-mysql

Comment: its the same code but not the same problem...the last time, it couldnt  show up in my admin page(backend) but this time its the main index(frontend)

Answer (score 0):

Your image's path relative to the path of your function is irrelevant. As far as that function is concerned the path to the image is just a string.

You need to make sure the path to the  image is correct relative to the HTML file that's viewing it. The easy way to make it work is to just use the full URL to the image:

`www.something.com/admin/images/myimage.php`